# What is the point of the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning with a state setter?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am building a pagination with React.

The app manages a pagination and a search using states. I'd like to reset the pagination to Page 1 when the search term changes.

```
// Simplified example

function useSearchTerm() {
  return React.useState("");
}

function usePage() {
  return React.useState(1);
}

function MyComponent(){
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useSearchTerm()
  const [page, setPage] = usePage();

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1);
  }, [searchTerm]); // <-- Here is the ESLint warning
}
```

This is getting me the ESLint warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setPage'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps` on the useEffect hook.

But of course if I include setPage on the dependencies, the effect is called at each render.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong on this use case?

Comment: *"But of course if I include setPage on the dependencies, the effect is called at each render."* - That shouldn't be the case with normal state setters, I suspect that `usePage` intermediary function is the source of the problem.  **That** function is new on every render, so it's likely in some way polluting React's ability to track that `setPage` itself wouldn't be new, or is in some way causing React to return a new `setPage` on every render.  Take out that intermediate step and just create the state value/setter using `useState` directly.  Does the problem persist?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, you're right. I thought it did but the problem does not persist.

Answer (score 2):

This intermediary function appears to be the problem:

```
function usePage() {
  return React.useState(1);
}
```

The state setter function returned by `useState` *itself* isn't re-created on every render, but it would appear that invoking it through this external function is breaking that.  Which is resulting in the dependency changing as observed by the `useEffect` dependency array.

If you don't need this `usePage` function (in the example shown you don't, but there may exist cases in a larger context where it makes sense) then just remove it entirely and use `useState` directly:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState("");
```

Generally one wouldn't want to call hooks within functions anyway, as it can quickly and easily lead to breaking the rule by which hooks must be called consistently and in the same order on every render.  For that reason it's best to keep hook calls in the main body of the component itself (and early in the component logic).

Sometimes there are cases where you *do* want a custom function to act as a dependency in `useEffect`.  Since a declared function is re-declared on every render, you'd encounter the problem you encountered above.  To solve that you can wrap that function in the `useCallback` hook, which itself also has a dependency array much like `useEffect`.  The purpose of this hook is to create custom functions which React can cache across renders as a single function instance (unless a dependency changes).  For example:

```
const myCustomFunction = useCallback(args => {
  // use function args, etc.
}, [someDependencies]);
```

Comment: *"[...] but this usePage function is"* If I understand you correctly, then no, `usePage` is not recreated on every render. It's defined outside of the component. I assume the lint rule has special treatment for the `useState` hook, but it's not smart enough to detect that the custom hook just returns what `useState` returns.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah, I missed that it was outside the component.  I've updated the wording to describe it a little better in that case, though the "fix" is still the same.  Calling these hooks from external functions shouldn't be happening anyway.  (Though these hook calls can be put into a *custom hook*, but that's another story entirely.)

Comment: What about `usePage` makes you say that it's a "normal" function and not a custom hook? (besides being unnecessary)

Comment: It is actually a normal function. I didn't really get that a returned object from a custom hook should be memoized with useCallback or useMemo. I added a useMemo and I'm not having the issue anymore